# python list.remove() function error

Tags: python

Hi guys I was just learning to write program in python and was stuck at one point. I was hoping you guys could explain/help.
Thanks in advance.

```
items=[]
animals=[]
station1={}
station2={}
import os.path 

def main():
    endofprogram=False
    try:
        filename=input('Enter name of input file >')        
        file=open(filename,'r')
    except IOError:
        print('File does not exist')
        endofprogram=True     

    if (endofprogram==False):
        for line in file:
            line=line.strip('\n')   
            if (len(line)!=0)and line[0]!='#':  
                (x,y,z)=line.split(':')
                record=(x,y,z)
                temprecord=(x,z)
                items.append(record)
                animals.append(x)

                if temprecord[1]=='s1':
                    if temprecord[0] in station1:
                        station1[temprecord[0]]=station1[temprecord[0]]+1
                    else:
                        station1[temprecord[0]]=1
                elif temprecord[1]=='s2':
                    if temprecord[0] in station2:
                        station2[temprecord[0]]=station2[temprecord[0]]+1
                    else:
                        station2[temprecord[0]]=1 
    print(animals)
    for x in animals:
        while animals.count(x)!=1:
            animals.remove(x)
    animals.sort()

    print(animals)


main()
```

So when I print animals it prints `['a01', 'a02', 'a02', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']` 
All of the elements in the list get removed until one is left except for `a02`. I do not know why this is an exception.

```
File:

a01:01-24-2011:s1
a03:01-24-2011:s2
a03:09-24-2011:s1
a03:10-23-2011:s1
a04:11-01-2011:s1
a04:11-02-2011:s2
a04:11-03-2011:s1
a04:01-01-2011:s1
```

Comment: It's dangerous to mutate a list while you're iterating through it. Quick thing to try: `for x in animals[:]:`.  Here's a question though. Why can't you use sets for this instead?

Comment: Hey @Joe I haven't learnt about sets yet. SO i am only allowed to use what I have learnt! Dangerous to mutate list while iterating?

Comment: Iterating, aka you're going through each element. You're doing that twice for the `animals` list with the for loop and the while loop. If you try to modify the list you're iterating through (like what you're doing), Python can (and often WILL) bug out. That's what you're seeing. If you can't use sets, I suggest that you iterate through it using what I suggested - it will iterate through a soft copy instead of the list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) in purpose to remove duplicates from list:

```
list(set(animals))
```

instead of doing this

```
for x in animals:
    while animals.count(x)!=1:
        animals.remove(x)
```

Comment: Hey. Did not know about that function. Will definitely read about it! I was doing it the other way because it was so easy as I have used it before

Comment: I tried doing that. says cannot accept for 7 min? i don't know why

Comment: DO you know why people are voting my qs down? is this qs not stack overflow standard?

Comment: @Newbie There's a brief period (15 minutes) immediately after asking the question when you can't accept an answer.

Comment: @Newbie I don't know why exactly, but perhaps it somehow doesn't meet so q&a standard, yeah. You should read this: [voting down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the list while browsing it, hence the error.

What you can do for your problem is using `sests`:

```
>>> list(set(animals))
['a02', 'a03', 'a01', 'a04', 'a05']
>>> a2=list(set(animals))
>>> a2.sort()
>>> a2
['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
```

Edit:
consider this:

```
>>> animals
['a01', 'a02', 'a02', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
>>> for x in animals:
...    animals.remove(x)
... 
>>> animals
['a02', 'a02', 'a04']
```

when you remove `x`, animals is changed, so the `for` can lose track of where it was. If you want to browse through the list, you have to make a copy and browse the copy:

```
>>> animals=['a01', 'a02', 'a02', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
>>> for x in animals[:]:
...    animals.remove(x)
... 
>>> animals
[]
```

Comment: So why is the error specific for 'ao2' and the others are working according to the code? any idea?

Comment: Just like I said earlier. Striking. :) Just FYI, your second solution doesn't work. One tweak is to add an `if` condition that checks if current element exists more than once in the list.

Comment: @Joe the edit isn't a solution, it's an example to the behaviour Newbie observed, and what can be done to solve that.